# Using Word User Info in Mail Merge

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have a bunch of Word templates that merge data from a SQL database.  What I would like to do is have a signature line on these documents based upon the user that is merging them. For example...If Jeremy Hammond is merging the document, then the signature would be his.  If I'm merging the document, then it would be mine.  It is not an ACTUAL signature, just a Brush Script font of the name.  Actual signatures might come later, but for now, this would do.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Word are we dealing with?

If you insert a UserName field into the document (Insert/Text/Quick Parts) and format it with Brush Script, then EXECUTE the merge (not just print the main merge document) does that give the result you're looking for?

If you proceed to the "actual signatures" stage and you store them as graphic images in a folder, then it should/could (depending on version of Word) work to embed the UserName field in the path information of an IncludePicture field.